# cases when it is needed to delete pointers in the deconstructor

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

In my textbook, I noticed that it deleted pointers in a destructor which I found to be strange. It then explained that the **address** itself on the free store gets deleted but the value located does not. My question is, are there any other cases to delete a pointer in the destructor other than it being on the free store? Should I just delete all pointers whether pointing to the free store or not to play it safe?

Here is commented code of what I mean:

```cpp
class ExampleClass
{
public:
    ExampleClass(); 
    ~ExampleClass() { delete pNum; };

    int exampleMethod() {
        pNum = new int(5);
        return *pNum;
    } /*
      when I call exampleMethod in main(), 
      it assigns a pointer to an address on the free store and the value
      of the address holds 5. When the destructor is called, the pointer is called but the value is
      stranded on the free store and will cause a memory leak. 

      My question is, is it a general rule that we only need to delete pointers 
      in the destructor that to the free store or are there other cases where we need to delete pointers in the destructor?
      */ 

private:
    int* pNum;
};
```

Any explanation would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Ideally, you won't be writing many classes where you `new` or `delete` anything. C++ comes with all kinds of cool containers like `std::string` and `std::vector` that let you accomplish many things without ever worrying about them. But if you absolutely have to, the rule of thumb is that each `new` should be accompanied by exactly one corresponding `delete`, and each `new[]` should be accompanied by exactly one corresponding `delete[]`.

Comment: And when you really need to use your own pointers, try to use smart pointers. And when even that isn't enough, and you really need to use plain, raw and non-owning pointers then remember to initialize them in the constructor (for example in the shown code, what happens if the user never calls `exampleMethod`?). And implement [the rule of three or five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: If you never call `exampleMethod`, the destructor will try to delete *something* from an uninitialized variable. And if you're lucky, the program will crash. If you call the method three times, you are guaranteed to leak two bits of memory that can never be freed. This code can teach you what not to do, not sure there is a positive lesson here.

Comment: *are there other cases where we need to delete pointers in the destructor?* -- This is overcomplicating the issue.  You "delete the pointers" when you have to, whether it is in the destructor or somewhere else.  You write the code, and you determine by the logic of the code where things should be done.  If you want a class that is responsible for the total ownership of the pointer and dynamically allocated memory, then go to the **Managing resources** section of the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: Also, the proper term is *destructor*, not *deconstructor*.

Answer (score 1):

You dont delete the pointer, but what it points to. `delete pNum;` does not delete `pNum` but the integer that `pNum` points to. When `pNum` does not point to an `int` that was allocated via `new` or a `nullptr` then `delete pNum;` is wrong, it is undefined. You might get a crash, or something else.

For example:

```
{
    ExampleClass oh_my;
}
```

Here, an instance of your class is constructed. Its `pNum` is not initialized. When it goes out of scope, the destructor calls `delete pNum;` and invokes undefined behavior.

Your class very nicely illustrates why it is error prone to manually manage resources. If you do manage a resource you need to follow the rule of 3/5. And typically, managing a resource is enough for a class, so it shouldn't do anything but manage the resource. Such classes are rather boring. They acquire a resource in their constructor and release it in the destructor and implement the rule of 5, but typically don't do much else. `std::unique_ptr` is such a class.

If you use `std::unique_ptr`, or other smart pointers or container, or your own custom rule of 5-class then the class that uses them neither needs new, nor manually delete something. You can follow the rule of 0:

```
class ExampleClass
{
public:

    int exampleMethod() {
        pNum = std::make_unique<int>(42);
        return *pNum;
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> pNum;
};
```

However, if you do allocate something via `new` then you must delete it via `delete`, else you have a memory leak.